# Should I write an answer and have it closed immediately as duplicate as an effort to provide more access points?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicates, exact-duplicates

I read [a question about `systemd`](https://serverfault.com/questions/840996/modify-systemd-unit-file-without-altering-upstream-unit-file). The question is good, the answers are good.

When reading it, I realized that I had a similar question, but phrased differently. The original question is

> modify systemd unit file without altering upstream unit file

and I would have asked

> Are systemd configuration files cumulative?

None of the wording is better - they both raise the same problem and have the same answers. The second one is obviously not indexed by Google.

**It is a good practice to write a question knowing that it is a duplicate for the sake of increasing the likehood of having it found?**

As a side though, it may be interesting to have the option to add alternative questions to a question in order to do what I am asking for without creating duplicates.

Answer (score 11):

> None of the wording is better - they both raise the same problem and have the same answers. The second one is obviously not indexed by Google.

They are then duplicates and you create work for the community in having to close them as such.

I don't think it would be particularly difficult to reword/extend the original question to add to the honeypot. That's probably preferable.